# SQL query using %s in Python 3.3

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve data from a MySQL-database.

```
A = "James"
query = ("SELECT * FROM DB.tblusers WHERE UserName = %s ")
c = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='DB')
cur1 = c.cursor()
cur1.execute(query, A)
```

Gives the following error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 1
```

But the SQL works in the mySQL Workbench. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`A` should be a tuple, try with `A = ("James",)`

see documentation of [MySQLCursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

---

EDIT: added a comma, thanks to "swordofpain" (I learned something)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't work "alone", but added another criteria (department) and then it's ok.