# Python mysql connector error in execute query

Tags: python, mysql

I know there're similar questions regarding this topic in Stackoverflow, like these ones:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303677/1876345
- [SQL query using %s in Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817827/sql-query-using-s-in-python-3-3)
- [mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (4200): You have an error in your SQL syntax;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665819/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1064-4200-you-have-an-error-in-your)

But i still encounter an error passing a variable at moment execute is run.

Option #1

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
dbname = 'ssl'
mycursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE {}'.format(dbname))
```

And I get this error
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ssl' at line 1`

Option 2

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
dbname = 'ssl'
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %s ", (dbname))
```

Getting similar error: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1`

Any idea why?

Comment: try this `mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %(db)s ", {"db": db_name,})`

Comment: perhaps missing semicolon? `CREATE DATABASE db_name;`?

Comment: have you checked it dbname  is actually set with anything?

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes `mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %(db)s ", {"db": dbname,})` is giving the same error `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ssl'' at line 1
`

Comment: @nbk it's. Even in the error appears `ssl`

Comment: on my system HOAT and CI_PROJECT_NAME is not set as enviroment variables, so when you cheked that check the mysql connection if it throws an error

Comment: enviromental variable HOAT and CI_PROJECT_NAME have the value of ssl in my side

Comment: If I change the value to a normal name, gets the same error. `dbname = 'ssl' mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE %(db)s ", {"db": dbname,})`
Getting the same error `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ssl'' at line 1`

Comment: then show us your connection string, i doubt that that this runs withouit error

Comment: see also the manula for ssl connections https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

Comment: @nbk looks like the problem is the value for `ssl` with `ssl1` works. Never thought about it. Thanks!